# Change guest account photo in Mavericks?

Tags: macos, photos, user-account, guest-account

In Mavericks, how do you change the user account photo to something other than that gray silhouette?

I've searched for an answer to this question and it seems people figured it out in Mountain Lion and earlier, but not Mavericks as far as I can find.  I'm using OS X 10.9.4.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The image is located at the following location. Change it and reboot.

```
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/LoginUIKit.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LoginUICore.framework/Versions/A/Resources/GuestUser.png
```

<sup>GuestUser@2x.png is the image used for Retina displays</sup>

Comment: Note: System files (/System), should not be changed and can change with every OS X update.

Comment: With this break any signing?

Comment: Note: With recent versions of macOS (El Capitan and newer), you would need to disable System Integrity Protection first. If this is all you want to do, I wouldn't recommend the security tradeoff.

Comment: @timothymh You can re-enable it after you've made the change.

Comment: @grgarside Ah, good call!